# Comparing values many columns with one column of data and creating a new column with 0 and 1

Tags: r

Could anyone help. I want to compare values of many column with one column. If any of the column has bigger value with standard column's value than put 1 in the new column otherwise put 0. 
I have many files so I want to use it in a loop.

```
df:
    Names   Standard    Das Dss Tri Tet
    Aa  32  42  21  45  34
    Ab  23  25  43  43  32
    Ac  43  34  23  32  23
    Ad  23  24  33  12  23
    Ae  14  24  12  20  24
    Af  43  42  13  12  43
    Ag  12  13  22  13  22
    Ah  32  32  42  42  23
```

Output:

```
 Names  Standard    Das Dss Tri Tet Difference  No_Difference   Names_Difference    Total
Aa  32  42  21  45  34  15  3   Das, Tri, Tet   1
Ab  23  25  43  43  32  52  4   Das,Dss,Tri,Tet 1
Ac  43  34  23  32  23  0   0   NA  0
Ad  23  24  33  12  23  10  2   Das,Dss 1
Ae  14  24  12  20  24  26  4   Das,Tri,Tet 1
Af  43  42  13  12  43  0   0   NA  0
Ag  12  13  22  13  22  22  4   Das,Dss,Tri,Tet 1
Ah  32  32  42  42  23  20  2   Dss,Tri 1
```

I am using this code provided by @adibender:

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind, apply(df[, -1], 1, function(z) {
        ind <- z[2:5] > z[1]
        return(cbind.data.frame( Total= if(z[2:5]>z[1]{'1'} else {'0'},
                        Difference = sum(z[2:5][ind] - z[1]), 
                        No_Difference = sum(ind), 
                        Names_Difference = paste(colnames(df[3:6])[ind], 
                                collapse = ", ")
                ))
    }))

df <- cbind(df, df2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not tollay sure what you yare looking for but the following command will add a new column, `Total`, to the data frame indicating whether any value in the row is higher than the one in `Standard`:

```
transform(df, Total = as.integer(apply(df[-(1:2)], 1, max) > Standard))
```

Then result:

```
  Names Standard Das Dss Tri Tet Total
1    Aa       32  42  21  45  34     1
2    Ab       23  25  43  43  32     1
3    Ac       43  34  23  32  23     0
4    Ad       23  24  33  12  23     1
5    Ae       14  24  12  20  24     1
6    Af       43  42  13  12  43     0
7    Ag       12  13  22  13  22     1
8    Ah       32  32  42  42  23     1
```

Comment: Hohestein, I just wanted to calculate the total percentage of all the observations where values are higher.

Comment: @mariariaz So, you want to the new column to contain the percentage? For your example the values would be 75, 100, 0, 50, 75, 0, 100, and 50. Right?

Comment: its just I want to see what is the percentage of observations that are higher than the standard. As you can see in this case for me next step would be to sum up the Total that would be 6 and take the percentage. 6/8*100= 75. As, I have over 500 of similar files so I want to do it in a loop for all the files once I have this column.

Comment: each row represents replicates of observation. So, if any of the observation is higher that matters. May be later on I would be calculating that as well... Thanks for your help